I have code that I often use with Git, what is its equivalent in helixcore/perforce?
Okay, so I often use this code:
git reset --soft HEAD~1
To undo a bad commit on SourceTree. I'm tasked to work with P4V which I don't have as much experience with, but this has always been the 'magic' for me. What is the equivalent of this in Perforce/HelixCore?
I appreciate any and all help!

Perforce doesn't have an exact equivalent of a lot of git commands; anything that involves changing HEAD in git won't have a direct equivalent in Perforce because in Perforce you only ever submit new revisions on top of old ones (this isn't strictly true if you have admin permissions, but Perforce's core end-user workflows are built around the promise that anything you submit is immutable, and violating that promise via admin-only commands like p4 unsubmit and p4 obliterate will cause a lot of things to work poorly unless you're very careful).
If you want to undo the latest change, what you probably want to do is use the undo command.  You first need to identify the specific change you want to undo, which in this case sounds like it's the latest one:
p4 changes -m1 ...

I'm using ... to limit it to submitted changes affecting the current directory; you can also specify a totally arbitrary path and/or add additional filters like --me.  Once you've identified the specific change you want to undo, you can undo it just like this:
p4 undo @CHANGE

This is a lot more similar to git's revert command (which bears no resemblance at all to p4 revert, so don't confuse them) than to reset, but is probably the best path to what you're trying to do.  After you run p4 undo, the files are open in your workspace with the inverse of whatever changes happened in changelist CHANGE; you can p4 submit those files to actually undo the previously submitted change in the depot, or you can make further modifications to them, maybe to selectively undo some changes while keeping others.

so it's not the latest one, and it's a million temp files lmao

I appreciate your suggestions and will try them, will these help me undo a million temp files in limbo, not necessarily committed apparently but in "limbo."

Depending on the exact flavor of "limbo" it's probably even easier than p4 undo && p4 submit.  Try p4 revert -w ... (if you opened the files for add) or p4 clean ... (if you didn't).

If the files WERE added and committed, p4 undo @CHANGE (where CHANGE is the changelist that added them) will open them all for delete.  Still easy peasy.

It's worth acquainting yourself with commands like p4 files (is this file in the depot?), p4 have (what version of this depot file do I have in my workspace?) and p4 opened (did I remember to open this file for edit/add?).  These are very simple commands (way simpler than anything in git IMO) and they give you a lot of easy visibility into the state of your local files vs what's in the depot.  When you use those commands, your files will never be in a mysterious "limbo" state.  :)
